# keyboard shortcut for exit the compare editor and go back to original file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut for going back to file from the compare editor in vscode?

Just like what this button is doing:

[image]

Comment: `Ctrl+tab` might do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom keybinding:

```
    {
        "key": "f4",
        "command": "git.openFile",
        "when": "isInDiffEditor"
    }
```